# Counting duplicate items once while running 2 shopping cart rules

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.4

I have discounts running on items if they are bought in a group.
If one buys A,B,C (categories) they get a 10 $ discount and say they pick B,C,D (categories) they get a 15$ discount.
But what happens now is say there is A,B,C,D in the cart it becomes 2 rules.
A,B,C and B,C,D; whereas it should be just 1. 
I cannot set the Stop further rule processing as 'Yes' because then my users cannot buy 2 combos of exclusive items
So I need to exclude the items which have already become a part of one shopping rule. 
Similarly say I have a discount of 5 $ on purchase of A,B then picking 1 piece of A and 2 pieces of B gives a user 2 discounts.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the rules in the the Actions tab to check for products in the cart? Once you set the Conditions, e.g. $10 discount if cart items are one of each from A,B,C (categories), then make sure you apply the rule that checks an item from D category is not in the shopping cart. Apply this rule in Actions > (Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions) pane.

Comment: But in this case say I have a cart of A,B,C,D and the 10 $ off is on a group of A,B,C. The system should give the user a discount as he picked A,B,C but it will not as D is in the cart.